# XML file not reloading onResume.

Tags: android, actionscript-3

On my app there is a button, which loads an XML file located on a server. The XML file contains 31 pieces of info, one delivered each day, based on the day number. The user touches a button to reload the info, so it changes day-by-day.

Here's the thing I'm stuck on. When the app resumes from background and I touch the button, it will not pull the new day's info; it continues to display yesterday's info. If I force the app to quit (on the phone) and then start it again, it will load the new day's info correctly.

My question - how can I force it to reload on every button touch?

Thanks for your assistance. Here's my ActionScript 3 code.

**Update October 12 2012**: I've tested this, over several 24 hour periods, and found that it doesn't update correctly each day in the Flash 5.5 simulator. So the issue is probably not with the phone. I'll do more more work with the code and report back, hopefully with some improvement.

```
// Main 'Today!' button function
var myDateDay:Date = new Date();
var dayNumber:int = myDateDay.day;  

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

// Opens previously saved text file to read XML URL
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
file = file.resolvePath("qstURL.txt");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var QSTURL:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
trace("QST URL:" + " " + QSTURL);
fileStream.close();

// Load, process main XML file
var qst:XML;
var qstLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
qstLoader.load(new URLRequest(QSTURL));
qstLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processQST);

function processQST(e:Event):void {
    qst = new XML(e.target.data);
    isProcessed();
}

//Wait until the XML is finished being processed
function isProcessed():void{
    trace("QST is processed and ready for use");

    //Clear welcome message before adding new content
    if(contains(textWelcomeMessage)){
        removeChild(textWelcomeMessage);
        removeChild(imageNoAudio);
        removeChild(textProductKeyMessage);
        trace("Welcome items removed");
    }
    else{
        trace("textWelcomeMessage not onStage");
    }

//Text Section
    // Text field formating 
    var myTextFormat1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myTextFormat1.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT; 
    myTextFormat1.size = 20; 
    myTextFormat1.font = "Verdana"; 
    myTextFormat1.color = "0x333333";
    myTextFormat1.bold = true;

    var myTextFormat2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myTextFormat2.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT; 
    myTextFormat2.size = 30; 
    myTextFormat2.font = "Verdana"; 
    myTextFormat2.color = "0x333333";

    // Text field to display title
    var title:XMLList = qst.title;
    var myText1:TextField = new TextField();
    myText1.text = title;
    myText1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE;
    myText1.border = false;
    myText1.width = 315;
    myText1.multiline = false;
    myText1.wordWrap = false;
    myText1.y = 125;
    myText1.x = 5; 
    myText1.setTextFormat(myTextFormat1); 

    // Text field to display question of the day
    var question:XMLList = qst.question.(@day == dayNumber).text;
    var myText2:TextField = new TextField();
    myText2.text = question;
    myText2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    myText2.border = false;
    myText2.width = stage.stageWidth - 60;
    myText2.multiline = true;
    myText2.wordWrap = true;
    myText2.y = 180;
    myText2.x = 30; 
    myText2.setTextFormat(myTextFormat2); 

    // Text field to display clearing statement
    var cs:XMLList = qst.clearingStatement;
    var myText3:TextField = new TextField();
    myText3.text = cs;
    myText3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    myText3.border = false;
    myText3.width = stage.stageWidth - 60;
    myText3.multiline = true;
    myText3.wordWrap = true;
    myText3.y = myText2.y + myText2.height + 10;
    myText3.x = 30; 
    myText3.setTextFormat(myTextFormat2); 

    //Remove existing text field to stop overlaying when button touched repeatdly
    while (numChildren > 3) removeChildAt(3);
    /Add text to stage
    addChild(myText1);
    addChild(myText2);
    addChild(myText3);

other code ....

    }//Close function "isProcessed" - load & process main XML file
} //Close function fl_MouseClickHandler - 'Today!' button
```

Comment: how are you downloading and displaying the xml content? some code would be nice

Comment: Hi @toadzky. Thx. I've updated and added in the code section. The URL of the XML file is provided by user input and saved as a text file on the phone.

Comment: that code doesn't look like android to me. is that actionscript?

Comment: Yes. Actionscript 3. I just updated the question with that info.

Comment: is something updating the XML file for you? because you question says "when there is no change to the XML file and I touch the button day-by-day, there is no change of info" - which makes sense. if nothing is changing on the server, nothing will change on the app

Comment: First up, apologies, the app is not reloading if I update the file on the server. I just tested this and it didn't work. Used to. I'll update the question above

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml file is being cached by the OS.

If that is the case, try appending a random string at the end of your URL. Something like :

```
url + "?v=" + Math.ceil(Math.random()*10000)
```

Comment: Great idea that I hadn't thought of. So, I deleted the App's cache (in the phone settings) and then tried to reload but no change. I also deleted the App's data but of course that reset everything and took the App back to first-use state.

Comment: Also did the append and tested but no change. If I update the file on the server, the app will pickup the change and reload the file. Is this something to do with Android checking the modified date on the server file and if it is unchanged, then not downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally detectived this and found a variable that holds the date, was outside the scope of the main button. So when the button is clicked, to reload everything, it wasn't reloading the date and updating this variable. As a result, the day number was not updated and *this* is what is used to retrieve each day's information.

How does it get any better than this?